# Understanding a ttags error

Tags: acl2

I'm trying to make sense of an error message, so that I might consider
fixing it.  What's the right way to fix the following error?  Should I
go add `:oslib`, `:quicklisp`, and `:quicklisp.osicat` to the include-books
inside `books/oslib/rmtree.lisp`?  Is my include-book form wrong?

```
ACL2 !>(include-book "oslib/top" :dir :system :ttags (oslib quicklisp
quicklisp.osicat))


ACL2 Error in ( INCLUDE-BOOK "oslib/top" ...):  The ttag :OSLIB associated
with file /<elided>/acl2/books/oslib/lisptype.lisp
is not among the set of ttags permitted in the current context, specified
as follows:

((:OSLIB "/<elided>/acl2/books/oslib/rmtree.lisp")
 :QUICKLISP :QUICKLISP.OSICAT).
See :DOC defttag.


Summary
Form:  ( INCLUDE-BOOK "oslib/top" ...)
Rules: NIL
Time:  0.47 seconds (prove: 0.00, print: 0.00, other: 0.47)

ACL2 Error in ( INCLUDE-BOOK "oslib/top" ...):  See :DOC failure.

******** FAILED ********
ACL2 !>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend always using `:ttags :all` on include-books, or just omitting the `:ttags` argument entirely and suppressing the warnings.  For instance, you could do:

```
(include-book "oslib/top" :dir :system :ttags :all)
```

This may seem like overkill -- why would you want to permit **any** trust tags from this book when you know it only needs `oslib`, `quicklisp`, and `quicklisp.osicat`?  Isn't it safer to only permit the few trust tags that you know you need, instead?

The problem is: even though the oslib/top book only requires these three ttags *today*, it may be that, in the future, someone will extend it in some way that will require additional trust tags.  If and when this happens, you'll have to update **every** place that you have included it with this restricted set of trust tags.  Multiply this by many books and you've got a big mess on your hands.

At any rate, if you really want to limit the use of trust-tags, it's much better to put these restrictions in the `cert-flags` sections of your `cert.acl2` files, so that you can control them at the granularity of directories instead of individual includes.  See [custom certify-book commands](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/?topic=ACL2____3._02Custom_02Certify-Book_02Commands) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To allow books to include ttags themselves, place the ttags in parens, like so:

```
(include-book "oslib/top" :dir :system :ttags ((oslib) (quicklisp)
  (quicklisp.osicat)))
```