# Why is cert.pl complaining about ttags

Tags: acl2

Often I get the following error message when certifying ACL2 books:

```
| ACL2 Error in ( INCLUDE-BOOK "something" ...):  The ttag :FAST-CAT
| associated with file /elided/acl2/books/std/string\
| s/fast-cat.lisp is not among the set of ttags permitted in the current
| context, specified as follows:
|   NIL.
| See :DOC defttag.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004313/understanding-a-ttags-error

Comment: It's related but still distinct, as this particular answer addresses a common build failure that I see all the time.  I don't see the oslib failure that often.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to add a `<something>.acl2` file (typically `cert.acl2` works just fine) to the directory that contains the book you're trying to certify.  This `<something>.acl2` file needs to direct `cert.pl` that `ttags` are okay to use, e.g., with the following code:

```
(in-package "ACL2")

; cert-flags: ? t :ttags :all
```